# Riak simple SearchMapReduce throws IOException

Tags: mapreduce, riak

I am trying to fetch Raik objects using simple filters.
I have enabled search on the bucket before storing objects to it, and I try the following:

> MapReduceResult result = riakClient.
>               mapReduce("serviceProvider", "name:oved1").
>               addMapPhase(new NamedJSFunction("Riak.mapValuesJson"), true).execute();

I get this exception:

> com.basho.riak.client.RiakException: java.io.IOException: {"error":"map_reduce_error"}
>       at com.basho.riak.client.query.MapReduce.execute(MapReduce.java:80)
>       at com.att.cso.omss.datastore.riak.controllers.RiakBaseController.getAllServiceProvider(RiakBaseController.java:339)
>       at com.att.cso.omss.datastore.riak.App.serviceProviderTests(App.java:64)
>       at com.att.cso.omss.datastore.riak.App.main(App.java:38)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: {"error":"map_reduce_error"}
>       at com.basho.riak.client.raw.http.ConversionUtil.convert(ConversionUtil.java:588)
>       at com.basho.riak.client.raw.http.HTTPClientAdapter.mapReduce(HTTPClientAdapter.java:386)
>       at com.basho.riak.client.query.MapReduce.execute(MapReduce.java:78)
>       ... 3 more

any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to fix this issue...

apparently you need to do 2 things prior to storing objects that need to be searched in the future:

1. Enabled search in app.config (/etc/riak):

> {riak_search, [{enabled, true}]}

1. Enable search on the bucket:

> Bucket bucket = riakClient.createBucket(bucketName).enableForSearch().execute();

After doing that, this returns values:

> ```
>       MapReduceResult result = riakClient.
>             mapReduce(bucketName, "name:9"). 
>             addMapPhase(new NamedJSFunction("Riak.mapValuesJson"), true).
>             execute();
> ```